# Importing Word Documents Into LyX

Tags: lyx, msword

I found this  [link](http://www.oak-tree.us/2012/03/07/word2lyx01-2/) which explained how to import Word documents into `LyX`. I downloaded `word2lyx` and put the unzipped word2lyx  into `D:\` (`Windows 7`). Then created the new converter as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Then I can get new converter (here MS Word 2010)

[image]

But when I try to convert docx document to LyX, I get the following error:

[image]

I also tried `python “D:/word2lyx-01/word2lyx.py” $$I $$o –t article` without any success. I'm using `LyX 2.1.2` on `Windows 7`.
I would highly appreciate if someone help me to figure out this issue. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry you're having this issue, but I feel obliged to tell you that, while LyX is very much on-topic for this site, not many people here use it.  I would recommend though that you follow the idea of a MWE and try to convert a *basic* word file and then gradually add on 'features' until it breaks.

Comment: Also, look for log files or something like that. Just knowing that some error occurred doesn't tell you much. I assume somewhere, it must log details of the error. (Or if you are running it at the command line in the second case, do you get more information? If not, is there a `verbose` or `debug` option?)

Comment: In have `wvCleanLatex $$i $$o` for MSWord to Lyx conversion by default in a Linux system. Hope this help for Windows.

Comment: Sometimes, the simplest solution is to save the Word document in another format and then import. I have had some success using RTF as the interchange. Of course, you can always export to plain text and import that. You will lose formatting, etc, so it depends on what's most important to you, content or the "extras". Also, you might find something to convert to latex, and then import that.